# Should a duplicated record be added to the end or after the selected record?

Tags: gui-design, usability, lists

I'm wondering what the preference (or what makes the most sense) is for duplicating a record in a list.  I torn between copying the duplicated item right below the selected one or copying it to the end.

[image: List of items]

So for example, if Pattern #2 is selected, and I click duplicate, should the new pattern be added below Pattern #2

[image]

or should it be added to the end after Pattern #3

[image]

Comment: I would have thought it all depends on what order the other patterns are listed. Are they listed in the order in which they were first added?

Comment: @MattObee - They are not necessary in the order they were added.  You could insert (and duplicate) records which could result in a different order.  I might add later a move up/move down option as well.  Order does matter, but it can change based on what the user wants

Comment: Out of interest, where does the 'Insert' button insert a pattern? I assume either above or below the selected pattern.

Comment: @MattObee - Yeah below the selected pattern

Comment: OK. Outside the scope of your question but I wonder if people would understand the difference between 'add' and 'insert'.

Comment: @MattObee - That is a good point.  I wanted to try to keep the button text small, but I did consider making them 'Add to end' and 'Insert below selected', but that seemed like a lot of text.  What do you recommend? Thx :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/5852/discussion-between-matt-obee-and-swdevman81)

Comment: Another question: should the new item get focus, or the older one?

Comment: @JimmyBreck-McKye - I think the new one should get focus so they can see it being added and follow it.  Not sure if thats the best option, but thats what I'm going with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the patterns aren't listed in any pre-defined order, I would insert the duplicated pattern directly after the original. I think it would be disorientating if the list were long and the duplicated pattern were to be dropped at the bottom (or indeed the top). I assume it would be given a name to differentiate it (e.g. "(copy)")

Comment: +1 Yeah I think this makes sense, and as you mentioned in the comments above, this would be consistent with what the insert does.

Answer (score 0):

I'm tempted to say the new item should appear **as close to the 'duplicate' control as possible**, so users see the results of their change as they click the button without relying on peripheral vision. That would mean that for your example, the new item should appear at the *top* of the list.

However, putting the duplicate control at the top is probably not the best method anyway - I would suggest letting users right-click to duplicate, then adding the new element below the old.

Anything's better than adding the item to the bottom, though, because with lists that exceed the size of the container, new items will either be out of view or force the entire list to scroll (these sorts of tracking animation are very distracting in peripheral vision and take more attention than a transition like this ought to).